# Write on an unavailable nfs share

Tags: nfs

We have a legacy application which writes files on an nfs share.

Some days ago that nfs share could be down and we have some missing files.

According to the application's assistance when the nfs share is down the files are written on local file system. It sounds weird to me and cannot even understand if it is an application behavior or if it is normal nfs operation.

Anyway at a first glance the missing files are not present on local file system too.
I wonder what happens if I try to mount nfs share on a non empty directory.
Does it fails or files are merged ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above. When one mounts device on non-empty dir, then 
previous content of that dir becomes unavailable until one unmounts device from this mountpoint. For `mount` doesn't matter whether dir is empty or not, so it will mount as usual.

Comment: The missing files were really saved on local file system and I could find them following this [advice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37765/mounting-to-non-empty-directory-then-later-deleting-original-files)